# SwiftUI link each cell to new View

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigation, tableview, navigationview

I'm new to SwiftUI, I want to know how can I link my list if someone toggle a cardView to a new SwiftUI view like how I used to do with storyboard and tableView for each cell I toggle

```
struct ScrollViewCont: View {
   
    var body: some View {

        ScrollView(.horizontal){

            HStack{

                ForEach(tabs) { sections in
                    GeometryReader { geometry in
                        ScrollViewTabs(
                            tabText: sections.name,
                            tabImage: sections.thumbnail
                        )
                        .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: (Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX) - 210) / -20), axis: (x: 0, y: 1.0, z: 0))
                    }
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 250)
                    .padding()
                }         
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `NavigationStack`, to go to another view when tapped? See: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/navigationstack/

Comment: This time I fixed it for you, but please make an effort to format your code to be readable before posting

Comment: `how can I link my list`, what `list`, and link to what? `if someone toggle a cardView`, where is the `cardView`
 that you toggle? Explain what you want to achieve with the code you are showing us more clearly.
 What is the expected behaviour or results?

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine so "ScrollViewTabs" is a Vstack of image and text List as shown in prevoius code suppose to go to whole new page or SwifUI View file

Comment: @khjfquantumjj I'm sorry it's been long time since I used stackoverflow I promise won't happen again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example code, that allows you to present the various `ScrollViewTabs`,
then upon a tap "go to" another view.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var tabs = [
        TabSection(name: "الحروف العربية", thumbnail: "folder", SubView: "test"),
        TabSection(name: "الحروف الانجليزية", thumbnail: "person", SubView: "test2"),
        TabSection(name: "الحروف الانجليزية", thumbnail: "globe", SubView: "test2"),
        TabSection(name: "الحروف الانجليزية", thumbnail: "info", SubView: "test2"),
        TabSection(name: "الحروف الانجليزية", thumbnail: "house", SubView: "test2")
    ]
    
    @State private var selections: [TabSection] = []
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $selections) {
            ScrollView(.horizontal){
                HStack{
                    ForEach(tabs) { section in
                        GeometryReader { geometry in
                            ScrollViewTabs(tab: section).border(.green)
                                .rotation3DEffect(Angle(degrees: (Double(geometry.frame(in: .global).minX) - 210) / -20), axis: (x: 0, y: 0, z: 1.0))
                                .onTapGesture {
                                    selections = [section]
                                }
                            
                        }.frame(width: 200, height: 250).padding()
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationDestination(for: TabSection.self) { tab in
                OtherView(tab: tab)
            }
        }
    }
}

// for testing
struct OtherView: View {
    var tab: TabSection
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("OtherView " + tab.name)
    }
}

// for testing
struct ScrollViewTabs: View {
    @State var tab: TabSection
    
    var body: some View {
        Label(tab.name, systemImage: tab.thumbnail)
    }
}

struct TabSection: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var thumbnail: String
    var SubView: String
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much that helped me so much after adjusting some code, still have question I was trying for long time to make each tab go to different view (example: first tab go to "OtherView()"  second tab go to "SecondView()"), is that possible ?

Comment: if my answer helped you, could you mark it as accepted, using the tick mark, it turns green.